# Cambiar el tamaño de una imagen, manteniendo el ratio [Objective-C]

Tags: objective-c

Tengo un objeto con una imagen y necesitaría modificar las dimensiones de la imagen a un determinado alto (ejemplo 50px), pero manteniendo la escala (el ratios).

```
UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"peon.png"];
```

¿Cual sería una función que pueda hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar esta función, por ejemplo:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToHeight:(CGFloat)newHeight {

    CGFloat scaleFactor = newHeight / image.size.height;
    CGFloat newWidth = image.size.width * scaleFactor;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight));
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newWidth, newHeight)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;

}
```

Comment: Gracias , anduvo ok

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaria usar Assets.xcassets, tienes que poner la imagen y luego al asignar la imagen solo asi UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"peon"];[image: Agregas para cada tamaño que necesites]